# x86: how to get user input for 2 variables?

Tags: assembly, user-input, dos, x86-16

The following program prints star symbols in this pattern

```
%
%%
%%%
%%%%
%%%%%
```

My source code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data   
sRepeats db "repeats: $"
sSymbol db "Number of lines to print: $"

star db 0
line db 1
nl db 0dh, 0ah, "$"

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

print:
mov ah, 2
mov dl, '*'          ; symbol
int 21h

inc star

mov bl, star
cmp bl, line

je newline
jmp print

newline:
mov ah, 9
lea dx, nl
int 21h

cmp bl, 5            ; number of repeats
je exit

inc line
mov star, 0
jmp print

exit:
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

I want to be able to take in a number of lines from the user instead of the 5 (on the line with `;` comment that says repeat)

and also a symbol other than the `*` (on the line with the `;` comment that says symbol)

I have been trying to do it but can seem to get it correctly?

get 2 inputs from the user

- number of desired lines
- symbol

instead of the 5 and `*`, how do I do that

**The program runs fine but I just want the user to be able to decide the number of lines and which symbol instead of the default 5 and `*` that I have in place**

Comment: Do you know how this code works?

Comment: yes, I am just confused with how to implement the input from the user

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: we took it in class. Do you know how to add the input from the user?

Answer (score 0):

Read newline terminated integer; doesn't seem that hard. We will need dos function `AH=1` It's been a long time since I've done this. Let's break this down.

We first need to be able to read a digit. That should look like this:

```
readdigit proc
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    ret
endp readdigit
```

Given that we could write the loop that reads all the digits; but there's a bit of an issue. When do you stop. Why, on a newline of course. If I recall correctly, a newline gives you a 13 (CR) followed by a 10 (LF). I could be wrong and it's just the CR; in which case you'll have to adjust below. The following loop would consume its input until LF.

```
consumeline proc
consumeline_loop:
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    cmp al, 10
    jne consumeline_loop
    ret
endp consumeline
```

To put digits together, the loop body would be:

```
    mov cx, 10
    mul ax, cx
    add ax, bx
```

Weaving all of these together yields the result:

```
    ; Reads integer from standard input; output in AX
    ; clobbers BX, CX, DX
readint16 proc
    ; Initial state
    xor ax, ax
    mov cx, 10
readint16_loop:
    xchg ax, bx
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0
    xchg ax, bx
    cmp bl, 13
    je readint16_loop
    cmp bl, 10
    je readint16_exit
    mul cx
    sub bl, '0'
    add ax, bx
    jmp readint16_loop
readint16_exit:
    ret
endp readint16
```

Copying and pasting this block will get you caught. You need to understand it and write it anew in your own code.

Comment: Sorry, I am bit confused, where is the symbol stored?
Specific to my code, where should I make changes/additions?

Comment: @user18147042: Immediately after `call readint16` you will find the value in register `AX`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. Where should I implement it in my code?

Comment: @user18147042: I am not going to hand you homework on a silver platter. Application of the answer is left to the asker.